# TextField Xcode 11 Binding String problem

Tags: string, textfield, swiftui

I have a file called PDFManager , which is in charge to create and save the pdf file.

on PDFManager I create the var nameCPT : String = "" and from the ContentView i'm try to fill this var with a value from a textfield

problem is, Xcode give me the error say "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding'"

I tried on pdf manager create a var with @State but still not working
any idea how to pass the value of my textField to PDFManager?

thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var lm : PDFManager

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            fakebar
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                TextField("Insert Nome CPT", text: lm.nameCPT). 
               // not working, I try with $lm.nameCPT but still not working
                    .padding(.leading)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@Observed` property wrapper to allow the property being observed and comply with `ObservableObject` in your PDFManager class.

```
class PDFManager:ObservableObject {
    var nameCPT:String = "test"
}
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var lm : PDFManager = PDFManager()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                TextField("Insert Nome CPT", text: $lm.nameCPT)
                    .padding(.leading)
                Button(action:{
                    // Prints the value stored in your PDF manager
                    print(self.lm.nameCPT)
                }){
                    Text("Check")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```